# Default arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc Architecture/CPU/fpu Flags

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

How can I print the used/default options for

- `-march`
- `-mcpu`
- `-mfpu`
- `-mtune`

for a specific cross compiler (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -E -v`

For instance on Raspberry Pi:

> $ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -E -v Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian
>   8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions **--with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard** --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf Thread model: posix gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)

On my x86 laptop:

> $ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -E -v Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro
>   7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions **--with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb** --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include Thread model: posix gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

As you can notice RaspberryPi builds with `armv6` by default (RPI0 uses a ARM11 - based on ARMv6 architecture) while `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` ships with Ubuntu uses `armv7-a` - probably the most spread ARM 32bit architecture for Linux.

By default multi-arch GCC does not tune for any processor as its primarily targets are architecture.

Comment: Would you consider using blockquote `>` instead of  \` for formatting? It's one long line, that's hard to scroll. I think a short comment about relantionship for example that `--with-cpu=something` sets the default for `-mcpu` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

after building a sample , run readelf -a command over executable for checking architecuture .